# Add Feature with Index Difference to Next Row with Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across a problem with Pandas in Python which I cannot solve unfortunately.
The problem can be split into different parts, explaining some of it would already be a great help! I could do it iterating over all rows, but out of performance reasons naturally I want to avoid that.

So I have a dataframe with columns 'A' and 'B'. Column B ist mostly 0s, with some 1s. Now in column A I want to insert in each row the index distance to the next row where in B there is a 1.
An example output should look as follows:

```
   A   B
0  1   0
1  0   1
2  2   0
3  1   0
4  0   1
```

Then, if that could be done, I would even go further and look n rows in B ahead, if certain conditions are in these n rows in A we want to set a different value, e.g. -1.

Thank you!

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want. Can you be more specific.

Comment: Mh okay. So in every row I want column A to have the value "number of rows until a row where B = ". So in my example above we see that in row 1 and 4 B = 1. Thus in row 0 the difference is "1 row", in row 1 "0 rows". In row 2 we have 2 rows until a row with B = 1, in 3 1 and in 4 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` on index then , `bfill` i.e

```
df['temp'] = df['B'].index.where(df['B'].eq(1),np.nan)
df['new'] = (df['temp'].bfill() - df.index).fillna(-1) # fillna if you cant find 1 at the end 

  A  B  temp  new
0  1  0   NaN  1.0
1  0  1   1.0  0.0
2  2  0   NaN  2.0
3  1  0   NaN  1.0
4  0  1   4.0  0.0
```

Drop the temp at the end i.e `df.drop(['temp'],1)`